# Spring Boot error: Whitelabel Error Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, thymeleaf

estoy teniendo un error como el siguiente:

```
Whitelabel Error Page

This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Wed Apr 27 11:35:37 ART 2022
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/formulario.html]")
org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: An error happened during template parsing (template: "class path resource [templates/formulario.html]")

Caused by: org.attoparser.ParseException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringErrorsTagProcessor' (template: "formulario" - line 15, col 89)
Caused by: org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateProcessingException: Error during execution of processor 'org.thymeleaf.spring5.processor.SpringErrorsTagProcessor' (template: "formulario" - line 15, col 89)
Caused by: org.springframework.context.NoSuchMessageException: No message found under code 'persona.id' for locale 'es_ES'.
```

Investigando que puede ser, una de las opciones era un error en los package que no este dentro del proyecto. Pero creeeria tenerlos bien:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

A medida que me vayan pidiendo y diciendo posibilidades voy adjuntando codigo... Por que la verdad, no se donde puede llegar a estar el error.

Éste error, me sale cuando hago un submit de un formulario.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title th:text="${titulo}"></title>
</head>
<body>
    <h3 th:text="${titulo}"></h3>

    <form th:action="@{/form/resultado}" method="post" th:object="${persona}">
        <div>

            <label for="id" th:text="${id}"></label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{id}" id="id" value=""><div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('id')}" th:errors="*{id}"></div>
            </div>
            
            
            <label for="nombre" th:text="${nombre}"></label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{nombre}" id="nombre" value=""><div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('nombre')}" th:errors="*{nombre}"></div>
            </div>

            <label for="apellido" th:text="${apellido}"></label>
            <div>
                <input type="text" th:field="*{apellido}" id="apellido" value=""><div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('apellido')}" th:errors="*{apellido}"></div>
            </div>

            <label for="edad" th:text="${edad}"></label>
            <div>
                <input type="number" th:field="*{edad}" id="edad" value=""><div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('edad')}" th:errors="*{edad}"></div>
            </div>

            <label for="fechaNacimiento" th:text="${fechaNacimiento}"></label>
            <div>
                <input type="date" th:field="*{fechaNacimiento}" id="fechaNacimiento" value=""><div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('fechaNacimiento')}" th:errors="*{fechaNacimiento}"></div>
            </div>

            <label for="personaFisica" th:text="${personaFisica}"></label>
            <div>
                <input type="checkbox" th:field="*{personaFisica}" id="personaFisica" value=""><div th:if="${#fields.hasErrors('personaFisica')}" th:errors="*{personaFisica}"></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <button type="submit" th:text="${boton}"></button>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: En lugar de usar imágenes, intenta siempre pegar texto: en la página web pone que es un error (excepción) en la plantilla de Thymeleaf `formulario.html`

Comment: Coloca el código de tu formulario.html. Ahí está el error.

Comment: Ahi edite la publicacion

Comment: @gisela coloca también el error completo a texto por favor.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez justo estaba editando esa parte. :)

Comment: ¿@gisela donde tienes los mensajes guardados para los labels, por ejemplo `th:text="${nombre}"`? ¿Tienes configurado un bean `MessageSource`? ¿Cuál es tu objetivo con el texto en los labels? Por ahí viene todo el problema.

Comment: @JaimeMenéndez si, dentro de package raiz, tengo un archivo de configuracion de los textos. ConfigTextos.java que contiene el siguiente codigo

Comment: [Continuemos el debate en el chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/135865/discussion-between-jaime-menendez-and-gisela).

Comment: Pude saber donde estaba el error.

Answer (score 0):

Revisa el metodo que usas en el controlador para asignar el mensaje de error.

Mediante BindingResult, el metodo rejectValue el cual yo estaba utilizando con dos parametros field y errorCode y recibia el mismo error, intenta utilizar el metodo que tiene tres parametros field, errorCode y defaultMessage.
Le envie el mismo mensaje de error en las posiciones errorCode y defaultMessage y me funciona en la vista cuando ocurre el error, lo muestra correctamente.
[image: Estos son los metodos que se debe validar y elegir el que tenga 3 parametros]